# Basic Datatypes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, types

What should i know about involving basic data types in SQL Server?

In my database i need

1. Flags/bits, I assume I should use byte
2. 64bit ids/ints
3. a variable length string. It could be 5 letters it could be 10,000 (for desc but i plan to allow unlimited length usernames)

Is there a TEXT type in SQL Server? I dont want to use varchar(limit) unless i could use something ridiculously high like 128k. How do i specify 1byte - 8byte ints?

Comment: please use the "sql-server" or "sql-server-2005" or whatever tags instead of "mssql" - thank you.

Comment: its hard to if it takes time before i can confirm if the answer works or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 1), use `BIT` - it's one bit, e.g. eight of those fields will be stuck into a single byte.

For 2), use `BIGINT` - 64-bit signed int

For 3), definitely do **NOT** use `TEXT/NTEXT` - those are deprecated as of SQL Server 2005 and up.

Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for up to 2 GB of textual information instead.

Here's the list of the SQL Server 2008 data types:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187594.aspx

Answer (score 3):

- Flags/bits, I assume I should use byte

Use "bit" which is exactly that: one bit

- 64bit ids/ints

bigint is 64 bit signed

- a variable length string. It could be 5 letters it could be 10,000 (for desc but i plan to allow unlimited length usernames)

varchar(max) is up to 2GB. Otherwise varchar(8000) is the conventional limit

Microsoft even put into a [nice handy web page for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 You definitely found the nicer overview page than I did! :-)

Comment: Do i have to worry about efficient and bit? if i have 12 bits or 16bits they both would end up taking the same space? (assuming its not indexed) just different inserting logic?

Comment: Just let the engine take care of it: it packs them in itself into bytes, so 12 and 16 will take 2 bytes. This is what the engine is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the document.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Others have already provided good answers to your question. If you are doing any .NET development, and need to map SQL data types to CLR data types, the following link will be quite useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx

Randy